# SharePoint 2013 - Associating Site Columns With Content Types Using the REST API

Tags: rest, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I'm trying to use the REST API to programatically create site columns and content types. Everything works fine until I try to associate my site columns with my content types.

By this point in my code the site columns and content types already exist...

I am sending a POST to the following URL...

```
http://mydevmachine/sites/claimsreports/_api/web/ContentTypes('0x01003E9D5AD94A5DCD46876B7BFFCEA9B60C')/FieldLinks
```

Here is the information I am sending in the request body...

```
{
  "__metadata": {
    "type": "SP.FieldLink"
  },
  "Id": "9400d057-ba2c-4ab4-9ce0-671b858fd849",
  "Name": "BusinessCategory",
  "Hidden": false,
  "Required": false
}
```

Here is the error I get back in response...

```
{"error":{"code":"-2147467261, System.ArgumentNullException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: parameters"}}}
```

I have tried several other options without success. For example, I have tried using "__metadata" : { "type": "SP.FieldLinkCreationInformation"} but everything I try with this __metadata type result in this error...

```
{"error":{"code":"-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"A type named 'SP.FieldLinkCreationInformation' could not be resolved by the model. When a model is available, each type name must resolve to a valid type."}}}
```

It sounds like SharePoint is telling me that this "type" is invalid. It seems like this should be possible with SharePoint 2013 since the documentation seems to imply that its possible...

[documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj245869%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

If anyone has any ideas I would be greatful for the suggestions. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the documentation, I would try that:

Endpoint (note the `/add` at the end):

```
http://mydevmachine/sites/claimsreports/_api/web/ContentTypes('0x01003E9D5AD94A5DCD46876B7BFFCEA9B60C')/FieldLinks/add
```

Body (wrap your properties in a `parameters` property):

```
{"parameters":
{
"__metadata": {"type": "SP.FieldLink"},
"Id": "9400d057-ba2c-4ab4-9ce0-671b858fd849",
"Name": "BusinessCategory",
"Hidden": false,
"Required": false
}
}
```